# iOS horizontal swipe room selection

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I am making an iOS app for remote controlling the lights in my house. I have a list of groups of bulbs (rooms) that can be turned on and off. My problem is selecting a room, I want it to be like this:

[image: slider]

You can either press the arrows left or right to switch the room, or you can put your finger, where it says Living Room and swipe left or right to switch it.

Can someone give me a pointer as how to implement a swipe feature like that? I know there are gesture recognizers. I never used them, but I guess they won't automatically make the text I want to swipe follow my finger.

I guess it would be possible to use the gesture recognizer and manually move the text to get the swipe "feeling". It just seems to me like there should be an easier solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in the end by using a pangesturerecgonizer attached to the label. It's pretty straight forward, I just didn't know pan is supposed to mean something like drag and drop, I thought pan would be something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar several times, and the most elementary way to approach it is to override the `touches...` methods on [`NSResponder`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  This will tell you when a user's finger touches the component, when it moves, and when they let go.  From that, it's pretty easy to adjust the position of your `UIView`, do some custom rendering, or whatever else you need.

Another, higher-level, approach is to use a `UIScrollView` and implement it's delegate methods.  Inside the scroll view are three elements which completely fill the viewport: the one you can see, and those to the left and right.  You watch the delegate events for the user adjusting the position of the viewport and as they expose an element to the left or right, you can snap the viewport into place when they let go.  Then, you adjust the three inner views to show the appropriate new content and reset the viewport to expose the middle element (which would then be showing the appropriate content).

There are undoubtedly many other approaches, but I've used both of these with good effect.

Comment: Thanks! I will try both methods and see what happens.